# Angular CLI proxy wss

Tags: javascript, angular, proxy, angular-cli

How do I proxy a WebSocket request?

I tried this:

`new WebSocket('/wss/api/v3/users/websocket')`

proxy:

```
"/wss/*" : {
  "target" : "wss://someurl.com:443/",
  "secure" : false,
  "ws" : true,
  "wss": true
}
```

But this gave me:
`Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '/wss/api/v3/users/websocket' is invalid.`

Next I tried:

`new WebSocket('wss://wss/api/v3/users/websocket')`

proxy:

```
"*wss/*" : {
  "target" : "someurl.com:443/",
  "secure" : false,
  "ws" : true,
  "wss": true
}
```

But this gave me: `websocket.provider.ts:20 WebSocket connection to 'wss://wss/api/v3/users/websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

How do i proxy a websocket?

Comment: I am having the same issue and don't want to go with the environment file solution. Have your been able to make it works? If so, can you post your final solution plz? thx

Comment: Sorry, can;t remember

Comment: Alright thx anyway, I had to take a chance ... debugging this is so frustrating :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because `new WebSocker(url)`requires a full url to work.

```
new WebSocket('wss://localhost:3000/wss/api/v3/users/websocket');
```

I would have a setting in angular-clis environment.ts file with the base url for the app, and concat a string with it.

Comment: I want to use a proxy, because without it I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error

Comment: You can still use the proxy, but the constructor for websocket requires an absolute url.

Comment: In your second example you included the schema (wss) but did not include the hostname (localhost, or whatever hostname your app is running on).

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` which probably means I can connect.