# Angular CLI: Proxy websocket with proxy.conf.json

Tags: angular, websocket, proxy, angular-cli

I am trying to proxy websockets using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` with Angular CLI but could'nt get it to work as I am getting this error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://stream/connect' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Here is how I instantiated the websocket and my proxy configuration:

```js
// WebSocket instantiation
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://stream/connect');

// proxy.conf.json
"stream/**": {
  "target": "wss://someurl.com:443",
  "secure": false,
  "ws": true
}
```

Am I missing something? It seems to be doable but i can't get it to work correctly!

*This closed issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6081 did not helped neither did this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281444/angular-cli-proxy-wss).*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I figured it out! If it can help anyone...

By default Angular CLI runs the application on `port 4200` and proxy is listening on that same port... therefore I should do:

```js
// websocket instantiation
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4200/stream/connect');

// proxy.conf.json
"/stream/*": {
  "target": "https://someurl.com:443",
  "secure": false,
  "ws": true
}
```

Hardcoding `localhost:4200` in the `WebSocket` constructor wouldn't work in every deployed environment because the url on which the proxy is listening would differs... so I came up with getting the location host and protocol dynamically and used it in the `WebSocket` constructor:

```js
// set ws protocol when using http and wss when using https
const protocol = window.location.protocol.replace('http', 'ws');
// get location host
const host = window.location.host;
// websocket instantiation
const ws = new WebSocket(`${protocol}//${host}/stream/connect`);
```

And BAM ... voilà!!

Comment: Why is the `target` switched back to `https` rather than `wss` in this answer?

Comment: `"ws": true` and `target: ws:// ...` is the key.

Comment: ```"ws": true``` has saved my last hairs.

Comment: To guys wondering if this works now too! As of angular 14 @Stefan 's solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

What helped me having both web socket stream and ASP.Net Core controllers was having both `"target": "http:yourAppUrl:portToProxyTo"` and `"ws": true` set up in `proxy.config.js` file.

```json
{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://someurl.com:443",
        "secure": false,
        "ws": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```